# Arduino Micro digital output pins floating / high Z

Tags: arduino-micro, digital, digitalwrite

so i recently got an arduino micro for a project needing the control of two stepper motors with the A4988 driver. previously i was prototyping on an arduino uno and everything was working fine, but on the switch to the micro the motors started behaving erratically such as random step direction and a random number of steps being taken. i've pretty confidently narrowed it down to the output pins floating, i've recorded the direction pin on the micro floating with ~2v being "off" and ~3v being "on" with a multimeter.
the thing is is that i can't find anything about fixing this other than doing.

```cpp
pinMode(DIR, OUTPUT);
digitalWrite(DIR, HIGH);
```

or external pull resistors and i've tried both pull up and down resistors at 100k and 330 ohm with no luck.

right now i have one motor connected to uno and one to the micro, the motor on the uno still runs fine with no external pull resistors. the below schematic shows a simplified version of how both the uno and the micro are wired.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fV4Vts.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

and here is the code both arduinos are running.

```cpp
#include "A4988.h"

#define MOTOR_STEPS 200
#define DIR 10
#define STEP 9

A4988 stepper(MOTOR_STEPS, DIR, STEP);

void setup() {
    pinMode(DIR, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(DIR, HIGH);

    pinMode(STEP, OUTPUT);    
    digitalWrite(STEP, HIGH);

    stepper.setRPM(100);    
}

void loop() {
    stepper.rotate(360);
    delay(1000);

    stepper.rotate(-360);
    delay(1000);    
}
```

here are some links to other related post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14174162/arduino-micro-triggering-with-no-contact
https://forum.arduino.cc/t/high-impedance-output-pin/655236

Comment: the arduino is plugged in with usb and im using the 5v output on the micro (and i can confirm its 5v), and im also lead to believe that the digital pins operate at 5v

Comment: Ah, sorry, mistook it for the Pro Micro.

Comment: When you measure such voltages on the digital output of the Arduino there is something electrically wrong. Do these voltages persist, when you are not connecting the stepper driver (only the Arduino without anything connected)? Is the 5V pin staying at 5V when you have the stepper driver connected?

Comment: ok after waking up and taking a second look at it it appears to be a wiring mistake on my part, instead of being wired to pins 10 and 9 dir and step where on 9 and 8 and i feel a bit silly, but before moving to 10 and 9 the driver was connected to pins 3 and 2 and was still having the same erratic behavior. and the motor simply wont turn if plugged into the adjacent pins ((2 & gnd) / (4 & 3)) and the program adjusted. so i guess problem solved for me at least

Comment: You could write an answer to your own question